# JSF Form Validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to persist a form in JSF page with many inputs. in parallel I added client side validation to process before entering to the actionLisner method.

The issus is that if I make the commandbutton inside <h:form> and outside <p:panel> the validation is OK but the action does not do anything (if all the fiels are validated). If I make the commandbutton inside <p:panel> the opposite happens, the validation does not work anymore and even if some fiels are empty, the method in actionListner is called.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

 <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="Entretien annuel - Personnel d'Agence"> 
 </h:outputText>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="body">
        <div align="center">
            <h:form id="CollaborateurViewForm">
                <h:panelGroup id="display">
                    <p:panel header="Détails du Collaborateur">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{collaborateurController.selected != 
  null}">

                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewCollaborateurLabel_idCollaborateur}"/>
                            <h:outputText value="#{collaborateurController.selected.idCollaborateur}"
                                          title="#{bundle.ViewCollaborateurTitle_idCollaborateur}"/>


                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
        </div>

        <h:form id="testForm" >
            <p:panel id="entretienFormPa" header="Entretien annuel - Personnel d'Agence">
                <div align="center">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:panel header="Détails de l'entretien">
                           
                            <p:outputLabel for="collaborateursItem" value="Entretien mené par :"/>
                            <p:selectManyMenu id="collaborateursItem"                                                  filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" 
          showCheckbox="true"
                                              value="#{entretienController.entretienMenePar}">
                                <p:ajax process="@this"/>
                                <f:selectItems id="entretienMenePar" value="# 
    {collaborateurController.itemsAvailableSelectMany}"
                                               var="entretienMeneParItem"
                                               itemValue="#{entretienMeneParItem}"/>
                            </p:selectManyMenu>
                        </p:panel>

                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:panel header="Saisie des notes de l'entretien">
                        <p:tabView>
                            <p:tab title="#{bundle.Personnel_Organisation_Commerciale}">
                                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
   <p:outputLabel value="# 
  {bundle.Personnel_Organisation_Commerciale_Comprehension}" for="noteItem11"/>
                                    <p:selectOneButton id="noteItem11" value="# 
   {entretienController.note11}"
                                                       required="true"
                                                       requiredMessage="# 
  {bundle.NoteEntretien_Requise}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="# 
  {entretienController.listeNotesPossibles}"
                                                       var="noteItem"
                                                       itemValue="#{noteItem}"/>
                                        <p:ajax process="@this"/>
                                    </p:selectOneButton>

                                    <p:outputLabel
                                        value="#{bundle.Personnel_Organisation_Commerciale_Actions}" for="noteItem12"/>
                       <p:selectOneButton id="noteItem12" value="# 
    {entretienController.note12}"
                                                       required="true"
                                                       requiredMessage="# 
     {bundle.NoteEntretien_Requise}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="# 
     {entretienController.listeNotesPossibles}"
                                                       var="noteItem"
                                                       itemValue="#{noteItem}"/>
                                        <p:ajax process="@this"/>
                                    </p:selectOneButton>

                                    

                                    <p:outputLabel for="commentaireOrgaCom" value="Commentaire de suivi : " style="font-weight: bold"/>
                                    <p:inputTextarea   id="commentaireOrgaCom" value="#{entretienController.commentaireOrgaCom}"
                                                       rows="4" cols="50">
                                        <p:ajax process="@this"/>
                                    </p:inputTextarea>

                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:tab>
  </p:tabView>
 </p:panel>

  <p:tabView>
       <p:tab title="#{bundle.Da_Divers}">
            <div align="center">
                <p:outputLabel for="diagnosticItem" value="Diagnostic : "  />
                                    <p:inputTextarea   id="diagnosticItem" value="# 
 {entretienController.diagItem}" rows="8" cols="67" required="true"
  requiredMessage="#{bundle.Diagnostic_Requis}">
             <p:ajax process="@this"/>
          </p:inputTextarea>
        </h:panelGrid>
      </div>
    </p:tab>
  </p:tabView>
 </div>
</p:panel>

 <div align="right">
     <p:commandButton id="saveEntretienButton" value="Enregistrer"
          process="entretienFormPa" update="entretienFormPa" immediate="true"
             actionListener="# 
       {noteEntretienController.saveEntretienActionPa(entretienController, 
        collaborateurController)}">
     <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Etes-vous sûr de vouloir 
enregistrer l'entretien ?" />
          </p:commandButton>
              <p:commandButton value="Retour" action="Details"
ajax="false" />

        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
             <p:commandButton value="Oui" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" />
             <p:commandButton value="Non" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" />
                </p:confirmDialog> 
            </div>
        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

I also tried to add validateClient="true" on the commandButton

Thank in advance !

**UPDATE :**

I resolved the issue without knowing what was the source. I go back to the initial example given on primefaces showcase, I added my fields one by one. Know all is good

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: minimal example done

Comment: Sorry, that's really not a [mcve]. Right now you're basically implying that your problem is totally solved when you remove e.g. `style="font-weight:bold"` or `<br />` from your code snippet. But this is not true. Then why did you include that anyway? So many irrelevant noise in the code makes it so much harder for us to spot your real problem by just reading the code. This way you will end up getting ignored. Please carefuly re-read the link posted by Jasper and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. Being able to create a real [mcve] will also make you a much better developer. Win-win.

Comment: Hello BalusC. You're right, I edit another time my code to be more minimal as you asked. Hope this time it's better than the first code and the guys can help me with this issue.

Comment: I resolved the issue without knowing what was the source. I go back to the initial example given on primefaces showcase, I added my fields one by one. Know all is good